# Desktop Client + EE Application Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, application-server

I would like to run a simple desktop client on an application server (probably JBOSS) in order to take full advantage of EE capabilities like EJB. 
I just need an entry point which will basically be locally accessed, and just to be able to start/stop the application. Is a REST interface the best approach to do the start stop commands, or is there a more "direct" way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps. I'm assuming you are talking about an Application Client?

> Step-2: Use the appclient-launcher to launch the application client
>   container.   Now that the EAR containing the bean and the application
>   client has been deployed, the next step is to launch the application
>   client container. Note: Just running the application client class
>   through a java command will not get the injection working. You need
>   the launcher to provide the application server functionalities.   From
>   the command prompt, 'cd' to %JBOSS_HOME%\client folder. I have JBoss
>   installed in D:\jboss-5.0.0.GA so from my command prompt, i will cd to
>   D:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\client folder:   D:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\client>set
>   JBOSS_HOME=d:\jboss-5.0.0.GA D:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\client>set
>   JAVA_HOME=c:\jdk1.6.0_10 D:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\client>set
>   PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%   Now use the following command to launch
>   the application client container:
>   D:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\client>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
>   -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory -Djava.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099 -classpath "%JBOSS_HOME%\client\jbossall-client.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\client\jboss-metadata.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-classloader.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-classloading-spi.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-classloading-vfs.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-classloading.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-dependency.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-reflect.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-kernel.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-xml-binding.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-xml-binding.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-vfs.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\jboss-reflect.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\common\lib\jboss-ejb3-core.jar"
>   org.jboss.client.AppClientMain -jbossclient
>   de.fhw.komponentenarchitekturen.knauf.stateless.GeometricModelApplicationClient
>   -launchers org.jboss.ejb3.client.ClientLauncher -j2ee.clientName StatelessClient

Found this specifically for Jboss. Not sure if this is what is meant by a more direct way.

The full text is located at [jboss community](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseAnApplicationClientInJBoss-5?_sscc=t)

Sorry, I just noticed the link is pretty old but perhaps it will give some useful information.